# Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Preserve Attribute' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've just inherited an old Xamarin Forms application and I'm trying to upgrade all the packages. App was initially running fine, but since upgrading to the latest version of all packages, I'm now getting a crash calling `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);`:

```
Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.PreserveAttribute' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Here's my packages.config file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="ExifLib.PCL" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.0.38-pre2" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.Labs" version="1.2.1-pre2" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" version="2.2.0.31" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Insights" version="1.12.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I see you are trying to use the Forms 2.3.0.38-pre2 packkage. Make sure you also update the Forms.Maps package to the according pre version!

Answer (score 7):

I closed Xamarin Studio and cleared obj and bin folders and started Xamarin Studio again and everything worked fine

Comment: This is the solution of many errors. We should try it anytime we know that the solution was working before. Because it's shouldn't fail suddenly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I noticed that the Xamarin.Forms package had an update. I updated this package and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message from a freshly created default Xamarin Forms app (Native, with Portable Class Library) after adding a new Form to the PCL (via the "Add New Item" context menu in Visual Studio and selecting Xamarin.Forms/Content Page).

It turned out that the packages.config in the PCL specified a different version for Xamarin.Forms than the one in UWP project.json file.

Making both projects use the same version of Xamarin.Forms by editing the packages.config fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path of project must have not '#' character

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had downgraded the Xamarin version from 3.x to 2.5 for all the projects. But somehow the .Net Standard project was not downgraded.

Started working after downgrading the .net standard project.